# Function does not wait until other function is finished executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

**Problem:**
I wrote a function to determine whether a certain bucket exists or not. If it exist I'll upload some stuff into my bucket else I'd create said bucket and then proceed to upload my stuff.

However I have some trouble with my workflow. If my bucket does not exist. The part `//upload my stuff` is faster reached than `ensureBucketExists()`is able to create my bucket.

**Source:**
[Documentation of AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)
[Create S3 Bucket if None Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367563/create-s3-bucket-if-none-exists)
[How do I test if a bucket exists on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842835/how-do-i-test-if-a-bucket-exists-on-aws-s3)

**My Code:**

```
let s3BucketName = 'myBucket';

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    // Connection 
});

const uploadToS3Bucket = () => {
    ensureBucketExists();
    // upload my stuff...
}

const ensureBucketExists = () => {
    let bucketParams = {
        Bucket: s3BucketName
    };

    s3.headBucket(bucketParams, function(headError) {
        if (!headError) return;

        s3.createBucket(bucketParams, function(createError) {
            if (!createError) console.log(`Created new ${s3BucketName}.`)
        });
    });
};

uploadToS3Bucket();
```

- I assume I have to use `async`and `await`in some way but I don't know them and seem to have problems correctly implementing them.

Comment: You can't use a callback this way and then return a value.  `return bucketExists` will always happen *before* `bucketExists =  null !== data` is executed.

Comment: Well how would I need to fix this? How can I tell my code to wait until something is executed?

Comment: I think you should invest an hour or two into getting familiar with asynchronous techniques and concepts, it will make life a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: @Robert Can you recommend me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumtion with `async` and `await` is correct. As a lecture I can recommend you this chapter about the principal of [asynchronous Programming](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html).

In order to achiev what you intend I enhanced your Code:

```
let s3BucketName = 'myBucket';

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    // Connection 
});

const uploadToS3Bucket = async () => {
    await ensureBucketExists();
    // upload my stuff... 
}

const ensureBucketExists = async () => {
    let bucketParams = {
       Bucket: s3BucketName
    };

    await s3.headBucket(bucketParams, function(headError) {
        if (!headError) return;

        s3.createBucket(bucketParams, function(createError) {
            if (!createError) console.log(`Created new ${s3BucketName}.`)
        });
    });
};

uploadToS3Bucket();
```